# MXChip AZ3166 without Azure IoT Hub

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, mxchip

I have been reading and collecting telemetry data on Azure resources using the MXChip AZ3166 for quite awhile now. May I know if it is possible to observe and extract the telemetry data without using Azure services?

Answer (score 1):

> May I know if it is possible to observe and extract the telemetry data without using Azure services?

Apart from using the Azure IoT Central portal, as per documentation:

- You can also monitor telemetry from the device by using the **Termite app**.

You can refer to [Quickstart: Connect an MXCHIP AZ3166 devkit to IoT Central](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-develop/quickstart-devkit-mxchip-az3166), [Termite: a simple RS232 terminal](https://www.compuphase.com/software_termite.htm) and [Getting Started with Azure RTOS and Azure IoT](https://coder.social/azure-rtos/getting-started)